Crashed: com.apple.main-thread EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x00000001701d95bc
My flutter app works fine on android and iOS(when connected with cable for debug run) but when i upload to testflight for testers to test it is getting crashed on the launch itself (8 out of 10 times).
What may be the cause of this issue as I'm unable to find?
The below stacktrace is from firebase crashlytics as it only happens on testflight build from XCODE 15.3 and I'm unable to reproduce it when connected via cable
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  nanopb                         0x6904 pb_check_proto3_default_value + 342
1  nanopb                         0x6074 pb_encode + 172
2  FirebaseSessions               0x413c FIRSESEncodeProto + 64
3  FirebaseSessions               0xef10 $s16FirebaseSessions17SessionStartEventC14transportBytes10Foundation4DataVyF + 232
4  FirebaseSessions               0xf198 $s16FirebaseSessions17SessionStartEventC14transportBytes10Foundation4DataVyFTo + 28
5  GoogleDataTransport            0xdfd0 -[GDTCOREvent setDataObject:] + 68
6  GoogleDataTransport            0xde60 -[GDTCOREvent copy] + 72
7  GoogleDataTransport            0x1b070 -[GDTCORTransport sendEvent:onComplete:] + 44
8  FirebaseSessions               0xa74c $sSo15GDTCORTransportC16FirebaseSessions27GoogleDataTransportProtocolA2cDP11logGDTEvent5event10completionySo11GDTCOREventC_ys6ResultOyyts5Error_pGctFTW + 176
9  FirebaseSessions               0x5efc $s16FirebaseSessions14EventGDTLoggerC03logC05event10completionyAA012SessionStartC0C_ys6ResultOyyts5Error_pGctF + 224
10 FirebaseSessions               0x5f80 $s16FirebaseSessions14EventGDTLoggerCAA0cD8ProtocolA2aDP03logC05event10completionyAA012SessionStartC0C_ys6ResultOyyts5Error_pGctFTW + 20
11 FirebaseSessions               0xd0c8 $s16FirebaseSessions18SessionCoordinatorC014attemptLoggingC5Start5event8callbackyAA0cG5EventC_ys6ResultOyytAA0aB5ErrorOGctFyAMcfU_ + 176
12 FirebaseSessions               0xd2c8 $s16FirebaseSessions18SessionCoordinatorC10fillInFIID33_A99E81F187A7BA47A5374F4DC053A423LL5event8callbackyAA0C10StartEventC_ys6ResultOyytAA0aB5ErrorOGctFyAKySSs0V0_pGcfU_ + 180
13 FirebaseSessions               0xaafc $sSo16FIRInstallationsC16FirebaseSessionsE14installationID10completionyys6ResultOySSs5Error_pGc_tFySSSg_sAH_pSgtcfU_TA + 48
14 FirebaseSessions               0xa9c0 $sSSSgs5Error_pSgIeggg_So8NSStringCSgSo7NSErrorCSgIeyByy_TR + 96
15 FirebaseInstallations          0x49c0 __49-[FIRInstallations installationIDWithCompletion:]_block_invoke + 56
16 FBLPromises                    0x5138 __56-[FBLPromise chainOnQueue:chainedFulfill:chainedReject:]_block_invoke.18 + 52
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x213c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
18 libdispatch.dylib              0x3dd4 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
19 libdispatch.dylib              0x125ec _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 1060
20 libdispatch.dylib              0x121b8 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 44
21 CoreFoundation                 0x3751c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16
22 CoreFoundation                 0x34218 __CFRunLoopRun + 1996
23 CoreFoundation                 0x33968 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608
24 GraphicsServices               0x34e0 GSEventRunModal + 164
25 UIKitCore                      0x22aedc -[UIApplication _run] + 888
26 UIKitCore                      0x22a518 UIApplicationMain + 340
27 Runner                         0x8f0c main + 10 (AppDelegate.swift:10)
28 ???                            0x1b3802d84 (Missing)


It seems like you're encountering the same problem as me a few days ago. I followed this thread.
The Firebase team also received this problem. It happened when you shipped your app using Xcode 15.3 and a lower Firebase version. In my case, it's 10.18.0 and the app crashes at 100% when launches.
You may either upgrade Firebase to >= 10.22.0 or downgrade your Xcode version to 15.2, as they suggested. I upgraded to 10.23.1 two days ago and the crash rate is reducing.


but im using firebase version in flutter as   firebase_core: ^2.2.0

Did you use cocoapods within iOS? you can check Firebase version in Podfile.lock.

ya, i can see its 10.18.0 in podfile.lock
Is there any way i can update this version, or i've to get it done by updating the pubspec.yaml file

simply cd to root project where podfile is, then pod update in the command line.
